# my search result doesn't display all items

Tags: search-results, groups

I'm testing the search server and I think something is wrong.

I do a simply search, I know there are 4 items matching, but the search result display only 2.

Are there a group by or something like this?
How can I remove this one?

I've implemented my own search too, with keywordquery, and I've only get 2 items aswell but not the same as in Common Search Results

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

I've added `kquery.TrimDuplicates = false;` to the KQL, which means that the query will not filter out "duplicate" results.